# Blank Page While Exporting as PDF in SSRS Matrix Report

Tags: sql, sql-server, pdf, reporting-services

I have created an SSRS Matrix report which shows 3 pages in output but when i export the report as a PDF, it shows 6 pages. One page is blank, although i selected the option ConsumeContainerWhiteSpace as True but still it is giving me a blank page as well the output pages are more than what is being shown in preview. I am using VS2013, kindly suggest.

Comment: Change your Paper size from Report properties. You need to test different size to get the exact preview in exported PDF.

Comment: You'll have to check your Body size, Report size and margins. There's a formula you'll have to take into account: Body width + 2x(side margin) <= report width

Answer (score 3):

As some comments have already suggested you will need to do a bit of trial and error with your page layout, page size and report contents to ensure that there is no white space pushing onto other pages.

The easiest way I have found to do this is to use the `Print Layout` option when previewing the report in Report Builder (In the middle of the Ribbon when viewing the report preview), which previews the report as it would be exported to actual pages.  If it is still not obvious as to why the blank pages are there, you can set different background colours to your report items and report itself to see which colours show on the 'blank' pages.  This will show you whether it is a report item or the report page layout that needs to be adjusted.

Answer (score 2):

Your tables are running over more than likely.

Click ruler button in toolbar and make sure width of tables + margins  is less than 11 if landscape and 8.5 if potrait.

Also if you right click outside of the report and select properties You can check your margins. I like to use between 0 and .5.